# np.floor_divide with 0 as denominator - no error on Mac

Tags: numpy, floor-division

```
np.floor_divide(1.0,0)
```

results `inf` with `RuntimeWarning: divide by zero encountered in floor_divide np.floor_divide(1.0,0)` on Linux but results `nan` on Mac with no warning/error.

Why this difference on Mac and Linux ?

Comment: can you provide the exact numpy version for both your attempts?

Comment: I guess you use a Mac with M1 processor isn't it? Can you try to build and check the development version of Numpy?

Comment: On mac numpy version is '1.19.5' and on Linux it is '1.21.4'

Comment: By "check the development version of Numpy" I mean building the package from https://github.com/numpy/numpy and check if you still have the error. I remember similar issues have been reported on Mac (with the new M1 processor). It is certainly a bug and it may have been solved recently.